# Rolling file from Serilog not working in macOs

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I'm trying to implement Serilog in a **.Net Core library** to have a good abstraction for this Third party and be able to use it on different project that are in my Solution.

So I configure Serilog like the example in their GitHub

```
    if(Log.Logger == null){
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
        .WriteTo.RollingFile("logs/myUsefullLogs.txt")
        .CreateLogger();
    }
```

And I log an information like this :

```
    Log.Information(message,ex,source);
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

If I put a breakpoint all seems to work perfectly but when I search the file I'm not able to find it.

Somebody already face to this in macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Log.Logger` will never have the value `null`, so your configuration code above will never run.

When logging is not configured, `Log.Logger` is assigned an instance of the (internal) `SilentLogger` class: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Log.cs#L43.

Comment: Ok, I will remove the condition & test later ( I do not have code  source access right now ).